# java jna - get byte array by reference java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference, jna

I'm using JNA and I get a strange error getting a byte array.

I use this code:

```
PointerByReference mac=new PointerByReference();
NativeInterface.getMac(mac);
mac.getPointer().getByteArray(0,8)
```

And it throws a IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=4, offset=8 also if I'm sure thate the byte returned is a 8byte length.
I tried to get that array as String:

```
mac.getPointer().getString(0)
```

And here I get successfully a String 8 chars lenght.
Can you understand why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PointerByReference.getValue()` returns the `Pointer` you're looking for.  `PointerByReference.getPointer()` returns its address.

`mac.getPointer().getByteArray(0, 8)` is attempting to read 8 bytes from the `PointerByReference` allocated memory (which is a pointer), and put those bytes into a Java primitive array.  You're asking for 8 bytes but there are only 4 allocated, thus the corresponding error.

`mac.getPointer().getString(0)` is attempting to read a C string from the memory allocated for a pointer value (as if it were `const char *`, and convert that C string into a Java `String`.  It only bounds-checks the start of the string on the Java side, so it will keep reading memory (even if it is technically out of bounds) until it finds a zero value.

**EDIT**

`mac.getValue().getByteArray(0, 8)` will give you what you were originally trying to obtain (an array of 8 bytes).

**EDIT**

If your called function is supposed to be writing to a buffer (and *not* writing the address of a buffer), then you should change its signature to accept `byte[]` instead, e.g.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
getMac(buffer);
```

Comment: Ok, but than how to read the bytearray values and not the pointer?

Comment: Using getValue() my jvm goes in ACCESS_VIOLATION error and crashes... :-( I can not understand why with getString(0) it works...

Comment: Take a moment and read how pointers work.  If you don't understand that, you'll only be guessing.

Comment: I'm betting your native code doesn't do what you're implying it does.  What is the actual declaration?  Does the native code write a pointer to the supplied address, or does it write data to the supplied address?

Comment: Your last edit solved my trouble... it was so simple, but I did not try that because i thought to use some ByReference object. Thank you.